# Limit Exceeded: Too many target object ids

Tags: apex, limits, mass-email

What does the error "Limit_Exceeded: Too many target object ids" mean. I couldn't find any documentation related to this. We are getting this error when we do mass emails from Apex in Salesforce.

Comment: Does it have to do with the merge field? http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en_US of 200?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm).

> You can list up to 250 IDs per email. If you specify a value for the targetObjectIds field, optionally specify a whatId as well to set the email context to a user, contact, or lead. This ensures that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.

Comment: Can you add the relevant information from that link? You know the drill. :P

Comment: Thank you. I was able to replicate the issue in sandbox based on this info.